# Japanese Date Validation - Comparison

Tags: java, date, calendar, locale

I need to validate **Japanese date** entered by user.

Let say user selects the `ERA` -> Enter DOB as `YY - MM - dd` format.

At server side, i receive `input date` and `ERA` selected by user.

now i need to validate entered date with the selected ERA, if the date falls in the period of particular ERA or not.

i know there is support for this in Java Calendar API, Also there is class `JapaneseImperialCalendar`, but i cannot get any clue how to use it, though it uses it internally.

This is what i did till now.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("ja", "JP", "JP");
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
        System.out.println(now.get(Calendar.ERA));
        Map<String, Integer> names = now.getDisplayNames(Calendar.ERA, Calendar.LONG, locale);
        System.out.println(names);
        System.out.printf("It is year %tY of the current era%n", now);
        System.out.printf("The calendar class is: %s%n", now.getClass().getName());
    }
```

**output**

```
4
{??=3, ??=4, ??=2, ??=1, ??=0}
It is year 0026 of the current era
The calendar class is: java.util.JapaneseImperialCalendar
```

suppose user enters , selected ERA is `SHOWA`, expected period is `1926–1989`

```
YY   MM    DD
34   05    28  // which is valid date
```

again

```
YY   MM    DD
62   12    28  // which should be invalid date
```

So need to build some logic to validate user input date with ERA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: the

```
now.getDisplayNames(Calendar.ERA, Calendar.LONG, locale)
```

returns the display names in the given locale, which in your case is Japanese. So the `??` marks you are getting are valid Japanese names of the eras, it's just that your console cannot print them. Change to

```
now.getDisplayNames(Calendar.ERA, Calendar.LONG, new Locale("en"))
```

and you will get a nice

```
{Heisei=4, Taisho=2, Meiji=1, Showa=3}
```

Java `Calendar` does not validate if you are setting the fields "reasonably" corresponding to the era, but you can request `Calendar#getActualMaximum(YEAR)` on an instance of a calendar in a given era to get the maximum reasonable year. Then, you can switch to that year to find the maximum reasonable month and repeat to find the maximum reasonable day.

Here's a little showcase:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale locale = new Locale("ja", "JP", "JP");
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
    Map<String, Integer> eras = now.getDisplayNames(Calendar.ERA, Calendar.LONG, new Locale("en"));
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> era : eras.entrySet()) {
        Integer eraIndex = era.getValue();
        String eraName = era.getKey();
        System.out.printf("Era #%d [%s]%n", eraIndex, eraName);
        now.set(Calendar.ERA, eraIndex);
        now.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        System.out.printf("Actual max year in era is %d%n", now.getActualMaximum(Calendar.YEAR));
    }
}
```

prints

```
Era #4 [Heisei]
Actual max year in era is 292277005 // current era
Era #2 [Taisho]
Actual max year in era is 15
Era #1 [Meiji]
Actual max year in era is 44
Era #3 [Showa]
Actual max year in era is 63
```