# How to convert Japanese Era date-String to Western date in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-api-levels

In Android i have to parse a `Date string("平成30年10月 24日")` having `Japanese Era` to western date for comparison.Can anyone help in how to do this?

I have tried this to run in **Android Studio** and it is working fine:

```
  DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("GGGGyy年MM月 dd日", new Locale("ja", "JP", "JP"));
  System.out.println( format.parse("平成30年10月 24日"));
  //output:Wed Oct 24 00:00:00 JST 2018
```

But when i tried in the mobile device i am getting **`Unparseable date Exception`**.

**Minimum api level for projects in Android Studio is 19.**

---

This is not the duplicate question with:
[Japanese Date Validation - Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606815/japanese-date-validation-comparison)

Here I want to **parse** the **Japanese String Date**.

Comment: Hint: get ready for next year.

Comment: see also http://javazuki.com/articles/japanese-date-introduction.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat-Thanks..I know to get it in Java8 but struggling with Android where *Minimum api level for projects in Android Studio is 19*

Comment: Have you seen http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/JapaneseCalendar.html

Comment: Also there is the three10 backport http://threeten.sourceforge.net/apidocs-2012-10-25/javax/time/chrono/JapaneseEra.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat- **chrono** does not support on api level-19 so i can not compile application

Comment: Could always roll your own, Naruhito is still young ;-)

Comment: Still Looking for Answer...